# Regarding dictionaries and maps question in hackerrank

Tags: c, dictionary, maps

My code has passed three cases but couldn't pass rest 3. It is showing an error that:

> Your code did not execute within the time limits.

How can i compact my code?

Sample input:

```
3
sam 99912222
tom 11122222
harry 12299933
sam
edward
harry
```

Sample output:

```
sam=99912222
Not found
harry=12299933
```

My code in C:

```
struct phoneBook{
    char name[100];
    long number;
};
typedef struct phoneBook phone;

int main() {

    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */  
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    phone array[n];
    char query[100];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", array[i].name);
        scanf("%ld", &array[i].number);
    }  
    while(scanf("%s", query) == 1)
    {
        int found = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if(!strcmp(query, array[i].name))
            {
                found = 1;
                printf("%s=%ld\n",query,array[i].number);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(found == 0)
            printf("Not found\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What was the question in Hackerrank?

Comment: They probably want you to implement (or use) a hashtable, something like this: https://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/

Answer (score 0):

Your current algorithm is a slow one. For each input, you will have to go through all the saved entries in worst case.
I can think of 2 better approaches :

1. use a hash map to store the names (names as key and id number as value). This is very easy with STL library if you are using C++.
2. This question is essentially a dictionary search. You can easily create a **trie** out of the names and traverse it.Worst case time complexity will be O(total number of letters in all the names).This will be significantly faster than your original algorithm.
   You can easily create a trie using linked lists in C.
   Checkout this link to know more about tries : https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/tree/trie/